# Is this a CartoDB named map?

Tags: carto

I am a complete beginner with CartoDB.

Somebody else in our organisation has created a CartoDB map of New Zealand.  They created the map by interacting with the CartoDB web site.  They didn't upload a config file or use `POST /api/v1/map/named` as described in the Carto named maps documentation (sorry, insufficient reputation to link to that).

And yet it is a map and it has a name - so in a plain English sense, it's a named map.  Also the config (its CSS and SQL queries) seems to be stored on the server - which ties in with what I've read about CartoDB named maps.

I need to get information from this map.  The method I use is partly determined by whether it's a named map.

The map I'm starting with looks like this when I browse our organisation's maps:

[image: map]

When I click on that thumbnail I'm show stuff like this:

[image: zoomed in]

**Question**

Is it a "named map"?

**Bonus question** (for additional gratitude or up-votes, whichever I can provide)

How can I add auth tokens for this map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CartoDB creates named maps internally in order to be able to provide maps with private data, with no extra user interaction which would be required in case that the map was created manually via the Maps API and not with the Editor.

Auth tokens for maps are equivalent to "password protected maps". From the UI, you can set the privacy option to the map to password protected and this will internally set up the token.

Comment: So the thing pictured in the question is not a named map?

Comment: From the image you can't know, as that's something internal in the map configuration/definition. If it is created from private datasets, it is.

Comment: Ah, so regardless of whether it's created through the UI or the API, it will be a named map if it contains private data.  I picked up your guide on how to get the name of my editor-created map from your answer to [my other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184412/how-to-find-layergroupid).  Thanks!  Have some additional gratitude :)

Comment: You can also create a named map from the API with public data, but the CartoDB Editor creates always a named map when using private data, as it's the way to keep things safe.