# CartoDB static maps API and named placeholders

Tags: carto

Is it possible to use static maps API using named maps placeholders?

I've a private dataset and I need to enhance some features at the output.

In more details, I've a layer of land uses and I need to create a PDF of an specific plot of my layer. I'd like to get an image of the layer with the selected plot enhanced over the others.

If it's not supported I'll try the hack using phantomjs + cartodbjs

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186029/create-a-named-map-with-a-base-map-without-javascript-or-browser

Comment: @iriberri thanks but I'd like to pass placeholders to the static maps API. I'd like to use the placeholder to emphasize a parcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the basics of retrieving named map images at: [Create a named map with a base map - without Javascript or browser](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186029/create-a-named-map-with-a-base-map-without-javascript-or-browser). Basically, you need to instantiate your named map to obtain the layergroup ID and then perform requests to the Static Maps API as it if was an anonymous map.

In your case, if your named map has placeholders (parameters), then you would need to include the values for them in the instantiation which is required to obtain the layergroup id.

From the docs [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api/named-maps/#instantiate), your instantiation request would be something similar to:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d @params.json \
  'https://{username}.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/named/{template_name}'
```

being @params.json a JSON file with the values for your placeholders, for example:

```
{
 "color": "#ff0000",
 "cartodb_id": 3
}
```